# How to position element's in specific way?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html div's and simple css style, something like this:

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.child{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='child'>
    0
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    1
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    2
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    3
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    4
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    5
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    6
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    7
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    8
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    9
  </div>
    <div class='child'>
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to change position of this element on mobile device to something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTcqX.png)

How can I do this? I was thinking first of all about flex-wrap and order?

Comment: `flex-wrap` and `align-items` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* enable the wrap*/
  justify-content:center; /* center everything */
}

/* create a hidden element taking full width
   used to seperate our elements
*/
.wrap:before {
  content:"";
  flex-basis:100%;
  order:1
}
/* put all even elements after the seperation to have a new row*/
.child:nth-child(even) {
  order:2;
}

.child {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  margin:5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='child'>
    0
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    1
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    2
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    3
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    4
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    5
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    6
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    7
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    8
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    9
  </div>
  <div class='child'>
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

- remove `display: flex` from `.wrap` and give `.child` `display: inline-flex`

**CSS will be like that**_

```
.wrap{
  text-align: center;
}
.child{
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightBlue;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```